# Question about changing the array value before sorting the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I’m developing the React Web App.

Users will have their array after entering on a certain page.

The array looks like this:
[image]

After getting an array, I want to resort the array by one of the values of startedDate

Here is my code :

```
 sortedCard.forEach( item => {
      if(item.startedDate === null || item.expiredDate === null){
        item.startedDate = '9999'
      }else if(item.startedDate !== null){
        item.startedDate = item.startedDate.split('-')[1]+item.startedDate.split('-')[2]
      }
    } )
```

I tried map, don’t work!
And change the current array to the hard coded one(the current array is fetch from server and passed by Redux), it works!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're trying to ask here. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (If you need React; I think from your description, an MCVE wouldn't need React.) *"I tried map, don’t work!"* Show us that.

Comment: *"The array looks like this:"* Post code, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text or of a console dump. In this case, just provide an array literal with the relevant contents. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for suggestions. But my main question, I can run my code with example date, not the rea one I had from the server. That's the reason I post a pic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After getting an array, I want to resort the array by one of the values of startedDate

You can sort an array of objects using the `sort()` function:

```js
const objs = [
    {
        id: 1,
        startedDate: '2019-05-01'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        startedDate: '2019-05-03'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        startedDate: '2019-04-10'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        startedDate: '2019-01-21'
    },
]

objs.sort((a, b) => (a.startedDate > b.startedDate) ? 1 : ((b.startedDate > a.startedDate) ? -1 : 0)) 
console.log(objs)
```

This code loops over each object in the array, grabs the property value `startedDate`, then compares it against each other `startedDate` for each other object in the array and rearranges them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. it helps me a bit, however, some values of startedDate are null. it makes the result not expected! Still thanks~ The other question is Im wondering why can't I change the value of array by  forEach?

Comment: If the values are null, this means that the structure is inconsistent, so I don't think it would be a great idea to sort that way. `forEach()` doesn't return any values, but your code is fine. If im correct, you're trying to sort by month and day? I would recommend only modifying data until you render it, or if it is absolutely necessary.